# Pivot Table String Comma Delimited

Tags: excel-2007, pivot

I have a Source of data and I need to show them in a summerized table.

Please see Output Sheet from atached file and let me know how can I make that

[Please find the sample attachment](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-2007-help/779072-pivot-table-string-comma-delimited.html#post2540260)

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to have a user defined function to make the comma separated list

```
Function MergeCOO(rId As Range, r1 As Range, r2 As Range) As String
    Dim vIdx As Variant
    Dim vCOO As Variant
    Dim Id As Variant
    Dim i As Long, str As String
    Dim c As New Collection

    Id = rId.Value
    vIdx = r1
    vCOO = r2

    On Error Resume Next
    For i = LBound(vIdx, 1) To UBound(vIdx, 1)
        If vIdx(i, 1) = Id Then
            c.Add vCOO(i, 1), vCOO(i, 1)
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then Err.Clear
        End If
    Next

    For i = 0 To c.Count
        str = str & c.Item(i) & ","
    Next

    MergeCOO = Left(str, Len(str) - 1)

End Function
```

Add a formula to column `L` in sheet Source

```
=MergeCOO([@[HS Code]],[HS Code],[COO])
```

Then you can add this extra column to your report as you see fit